# How to execute a command on X-session owned by another user?

Tags: linux, xorg

Is possible (by `root` of course) to run a command from console, that will be executed on X-session owned by another user on the same linux box/machine ? Example: Can `root` open `xclock` for another local user logged into X11 ?

Answer (score 1):

if the use haven'T protected his X session, it should be possible for any user on any network that X is listening to use the X server.

`DISPLAY=$host:$displayNum xclock`

Answer (score 0):

You would need to set the DISPLAY environment variable to that user's X display, or invoke the command with a `-display DISPLAYNAME` argument.

You may also need to ask the other user to grant you permission to use their display using the `xhost` command:

```
xhost +yourname
```

or

```
xhost +yourhost
```